# How to get revert message in Web3js?

Tags: web3js, abi, revert

I want to get the revert massage from a `send` method call to a smart contract. So I use: `receipt.logs[0].data` that is a string containing a hexadecimal value.

Now I want to to decode this value to get the revert message. So I use `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter` method. The main problem is how to give `type` parameter to get the proper message.

For example If I give:

```
    const data = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c51ccda68b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002774a57aab99b34000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003692f60f63a91b794ce70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000276853add131034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003692f61028c5e91fd7e7';
    window.web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com');
    window.ethereum.enable();
    web3.eth.handleRevert = true;
    let revertType = [{
        type: 'string', 
        name: 'message'
    }];
    const reason = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter(revertType, data);
    console.log(reason);
```

It logs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="messanger", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

And if I use:

```
    const data = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c51ccda68b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002774a57aab99b34000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003692f60f63a91b794ce70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000276853add131034000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003692f61028c5e91fd7e7';
    window.web3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com');
    window.ethereum.enable();
    web3.eth.handleRevert = true;
    const reason = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('string', data);
    console.log(reason);
```

It logs:

```
index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: data out-of-bounds (length=0, offset=32, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

The txHash in this example is `0x074e91fe5c1535d9bdc2bbc8cbadc0378c93eb06318401b1f341d844185430fb` on Mumbai Polygon testnet: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x074e91fe5c1535d9bdc2bbc8cbadc0378c93eb06318401b1f341d844185430fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's a better way to do this in Web3.js.**

---

```js
// index.js
const { Web3 } = require("web3");

const rpcProvider = 'https://rpc.ankr.com/polygon_mumbai'; // 'https://polygon-testnet.public.blastapi.io';
const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcProvider);
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);


web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then((result) => {
    console.log("Latest Ethereum Block is: ", result); // confirm that the HTTP RPC provider has been instantiated properly
});

const txHash = '0x074e91fe5c1535d9bdc2bbc8cbadc0378c93eb06318401b1f341d844185430fb';

web3.eth.handleRevert = true;

web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash).then(async (tx) => {
    if (tx.gasPrice) {
        delete tx.maxPriorityFeePerGas;
        delete tx.maxFeePerGas;
    }
    try {
        let result = await web3.eth.call(tx, tx.blockNumber); // mock a call to reproduce the tx, otherwise it's hard to get the revert error from just the past tx hash'es logs
    }
    catch (err) {
        // the following transformations are necessary to remove the extra strings from the error object (the ones that mess up with the normal object type access)
        let errFlat = JSON.stringify(err);
        let { innerError : { message } } = JSON.parse(errFlat);

        message = message.replace('execution reverted: ', '');
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

The output after `node index.js` will be:

```bash
Latest Ethereum Block is:  46569344n
You cannot buy this package again.
```

**The approach is the following:**

- Firstly, retrieve the original transaction *(using the `txHash`)*
- Next, you should mock an RPC call (it will not update anything in the blockchain state, and is just a helper utility)
- Finally then, catch the ***revert reason*** with the `try { ... } catch (err) { ... }` block

***-> That way you get the revert error details, and eventually trim it to get the message thrown from the Solidity contract's code.***

---

### Here's the web (browser) version

```js
const rpcProvider = 'https://rpc.ankr.com/polygon_mumbai';
const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcProvider);
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);


web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then((result) => {
    console.log("Latest Ethereum Block is: ", result); // confirm that the HTTP RPC provider has been instantiated properly
});

const txHash = '0x074e91fe5c1535d9bdc2bbc8cbadc0378c93eb06318401b1f341d844185430fb';

web3.eth.handleRevert = true;

web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash).then(async (tx) => {
    if (tx.gasPrice) {
        delete tx.maxPriorityFeePerGas;
        delete tx.maxFeePerGas;
    }
    try {
        let result = await web3.eth.call(tx, tx.blockNumber); // mock a call to reproduce the tx, otherwise it's hard to get the revert error from just the past tx hash'es logs

        console.log(result);
    }
    catch (err) {
        // the following transformations are necessary to remove the extra strings from the error object (the ones that mess up with the normal object type access)
        let errFlat = JSON.stringify(err);

        console.log(errFlat);

        const errParsed = JSON.parse(errFlat);

        message = errParsed.innerError ? errParsed.innerError?.message.replace('execution reverted: ', '') : errParsed.reason;
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

***The result is the following:***

[image: web3js-get-revert-message-of-from-the-past-transaction-transactions-browser-nodejs-web3]

---

**Conclusion:**

- In the NodeJS (server) environment, you should reference `errObject.innerError.message` to get the transaction's revert message
- In the browser environment, just `errObject.reason` is sufficient :)

---

*(Update)* Taking a closer look, it's clear that the difference is due to that I used web3@ **^** 4.0.0 (**4.5.0**, to be specific), and Alireza has been using web3@1.1.0 via a CDN source. Hence the incompatible properties. https://docs.web3js.org/docs/guides/web3_migration_guide)

Therefore, the difference between the NodeJS and browser code snippet versions is that there's no difference if same versions are used across environments.

Comment: Thanks, It logs: `x.html:120 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')`

Comment: Aha, the culprit is probably some kind of an incompatibility between the NodeJS and web Web3.js behavior. First of all, what web3.js version are you using? Also, could you please update your question with the new code that you're using, so I can take a look and try to help you?

Comment: Also, I see a problem with the RPC gateway that your using... Maybe it's just because my IP is not registered on their platform (`Upgrade to an archive plan add-on for your account. Max height of block allowed on archive for your current plan: 128`)... Not sure. Anyways, **could you try testing the code with something like an Alchemy RPC or the Ankr RPC (like I do in the code snippet above)??**

Comment: I am using Web3.js version 1.10.0, by this tag at the head of my html file: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.10.0/dist/web3.min.js">` 
After it I used all of your codes without the first line: `const { Web3 } = require("web3");`

Comment: I used your RPC gateway: `https://rpc.ankr.com/polygon_mumbai`

Comment: Would you please to explain this command `let { innerError : { message } } =  ...` so I can replace it with another code? What is `innerError` and `message` in this line?

Comment: Oh, I updated my answer with the fixed code... I'll write down the comments in a few moments...

Comment: Please take a look! :)

Comment: - In the NodeJS (server) environment, you should reference `errObject.innerError.message` to get the transaction's revert message
- In the browser environment, just `errObject.reason` is sufficient :)

Comment: `let { innerError : { message } } = JSON.parse(errFlat);` is an object *inline* destructuting synthetic sugar here, which is equivalent to `JSON.parse(errFlat).innerError.message`.

Comment: Thank you guy. Finally it worked by this code: 
`let message = JSON.parse(errFlat);
let reason = message['reason'];
console.log(reason);`
Also I deleted two commands `delete tx. ...` and it still works.
Please edit your code for using in browser.

Comment: Awesome!!

**To clarify:** *The `delete tx. ...` stuff is still required, because some other transactions might have `maxPriorityFeePerGas`, `maxFeePerGas` and `gasPrice` specified at the same time, and removing these lines will cause an error in those cases. `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas` are neutralizing the `gasPrice`, so they can't be used together anyways.*

**Re `reason = message['reason']`:** Didn't it work just like `message.reason` for you? These expressions should be equivalent.

Anyways, glad my answer was helpful  You're welcome!

Comment: Is Nodejs version of Web3js different from the browser version?
If no, Why is there this difference?

Comment: I used web3@4.5.0, and you're using a CDN web3@1.10.0, hence the difference (https://docs.web3js.org/docs/guides/web3_migration_guide)